# How do programmers add huge values such as those seen in RC5/RC6 encryption

Tags: c++, linux, encryption, bit-manipulation, byte

So as part of RC6 encryption, the key size can be up to 256 bytes and operations are performed on the key throughout the encryption process.  How do programmers store such huge values and perform operations on them? Specifically in C++?

Comment: a) `the key size can be up to 256 bytes` bit. b) The key isn't necessarily treated as one big number. c) Calculating something with huge numbers is possible if the data is stored in an array of something (eg. one digit per element) and operations like addition etc. are implemented as functions like learned in school (except in real life, there are some computer-targetted changes for improved speed and less memory consumption)

Comment: There are BigInteger libraries that can be used for this sort of thing.  As deviantfan points out, the key is not always used as one large number.  However, I looked at RC6 and you do need to do math on larger than 64 bit numbers, depending on your word size.  Take a look at gmplib.org is my recommendation.  If you can figure out how to compile that library for Windows (it can be done but I haven't worked it out yet) the library is supposed to be very well written.